# MS Word document is flagged as Ready only... but not on the file system

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, read-only

I need to analyze a long list of items in a table within a MS Word doc.  Naturally, I thought writing a simple C# program to process all this would be useful.

I noticed that when I use the Interop, it also creates a backup while it's open. That's a waste because I only want to read it.

```
            wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            wordApp.Documents.Open("yada.docx");
```

Well, I looked on the MS website, lo and behold, there is a read only flag.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open?view=word-pia

Naturally, I put it to use...

```
            wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            wordApp.Documents.Open("yada.docx",false, true,false);
```

Opps.   MS, as typical, shot me in the foot.  Although I did not alter or save the document after scanning the table inside it, suddenly now when I open it with MS Word, opens as 'Read Only'

And NOT as a file system properties.  It's something INSIDE the doc file.  And now I can't figure out how to get rid of that setting!

See the images below.  Any help is appreciated!

[image: File System is NOT a read only file]

[image: MS Word says it's read only]

Comment: When an Office document is opened it write mode, it creates a .lck file in the same folder as the document. That file is used to indicate that it already opened with a (read/)write handle. The issue might be due to a second handle being created, which finds the file already locked. See this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I could see the temp file being created, because I was watching the folder. It's name has a leading ~$... on it. There is no .lck file being created either by Word in the foreground, or by the COM interface.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Also, thanks for the link to the sample.  I think it's useful to read other peoples code, there is always a chance to learn from additional examples.

Answer (score 0):

All,

After hacking at it a while longer, I discovered two instances of "Word" were already running, even without my analysis program running. They were buried down the task manager list, without any UI open.

They were likely leftovers from the C# program being stopped during development and debugging cycles, leaving the orphaned COM instances running.  My mistake, I thought I had killed them.

It would have been useful if Word had said something like "Another copy of Word has this document open in read only mode."  Then I would have known where to start looking.

Also, the lack of a temp file, i.e.  "~$ada.docx", made be think there wasn't a copy open somewhere.

I killed those copies and now when I open the document with Word, it doesn't say it's "Read Only".   And the C# program I wrote for scanning the table in the document opens it as "read only", not creating the temp backup file.

So everything is working as expected now.